# Show text in vertical format

Tags: html, css

`<span class="helpBtn">HELP</span>`   **help text should stay inside span**

- It should display like this......
  **[image]**
- I have tried text transform but it isn't giving me correct solution.[image]
- Actually i don't  want to change text inside span. It should stay inside span like i have shown. It shouldn't be edited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try breaking word in css. If you need more spacing and your words are breaking each 2 or more letters use letter-spacing or just padding.

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
   position: fixed;
   background-color: green;
   top: 30px;
   left: 0;
   width: 20px;
   border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
   color: white;
   font-size: 13px;
   padding: 5px;
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    HELP
</div>
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/1hwd5j7g/

Answer (score 2):

try below code. it would definitely help you.

```
<div class="vertical-text">Hello Vertical Texter!</div>
<style>
  .vertical-text {
   background: #e23737 none repeat scroll 0 0;
   border: 1px solid #b52c2c;
   box-shadow: 2px -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   color: #fff;
   float: left;
   margin-left: 40px;
   padding: 10px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   transform: rotate(90deg);
   transform-origin: left top 0;
}   
</style>
```

Comment: I'm sorry. But this is not what i needed. I want something like that on my image.

Answer (score 0):

with CSS:

```
<style>
  h1 span { display: block; }
</style>

<h1>
<span> H </span>
<span> E </span>
<span> L </span>
<span> P </span>
</h1>
```

With Javascript:

```
<style>
   h1 span { display: block; }
</style>

 <h1><span> HELP </span></h1>

<script>
   var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
   h1.innerHTML = '<span>' + h1.innerHTML.split('').join('</span><span>') +'</span>';
</script>
```

Source: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-easiest-way-to-create-vertical-text-with-css--net-15284